# Format XAML Code in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

How to format XAML code in visual studio 2022 for mac with m1 processor ? XAML Formater / Styler doesn work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Edit -> Format -> Format Document

Answer (score 1):

Until now I can use it from Rider, I hope it will be available for VS Mac 2022 soon

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14932-xaml-styler

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34783820)